USB keyboard not working
I have a wired USB keyboard that i have connected to my laptop which runs on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. However when i press any key, nothing types on the screen. Maybe the USB keyboard is faulty? But when i randomly press keys on it, the cursor moves around on the screen. Any ideas what may be wrong?

Have you tried different USB ports?
Can you try testing the keyboard with your phone or tablet, whichever mobile device you might have, using an OTG adapter if applicable? Can you borrow a Windows machine to test the keyboard?

Thank you very much for the reply. There was problem with the usb port.
